# Quick print i++ (for debugging purposes)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm used to do `cout << i++` in `C++`. How do I get the same effect (print and increment) in Python?

It seems there is no `++` operator.

Comment: No there is no `++` operator. Simply use two statements. One to increment `i` and one to `print()` `i`: `i += 1; print(i)`.

Comment: Why is this question so (-1) bad? Interestingly, the answer is so(+4) good.

Comment: Probably because your asking a question that could easily be found on the internet. As in previous comment, all you need is: `i += 1; print(i)` Which is pretty basic Python. If you edit your question to clarify if you want a solution all one the same line or not, that would probably help. And by the way, `-1`-`-2` on your question isn't really that bad. [Bad is when your questions gets `6`-`7` down votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579965/missing-required-argument-in-python).

Comment: I prefer Stack Overflow then the internet. Not sure if a penalty should be applied in this situation.

Comment: Well that's great! But more often than not, the internet _leads_ you to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`count` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to achieve this effect:

```
c = itertools.count(0, 1)
print(next(c))
0
print(next(c))
1
print(next(c))
2
```

This is as close as you can get without using a statement `i += 1` since `++` is, of course, not supported.

The previous was increment then print; if you want a *print then increment* approach, use a custom generator:

```
def inc(i):
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

accordingly:

```
x = inc(1)

print(next(x))
1

print(next(x))
2
```

Note: these are infinite generators, don't do silly things with them.